# jquery ui sortable doesn't scroll in IE when placed in a scrollable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

checkout this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MSygf/3/ in Internet Explorer

```
<div style="overflow-y:auto;max-height:100px;">
<ul class="draggable">
    <li class="drag">Drag 1</li>
    <li class="drag">Drag 2</li>
    <li class="drag">Drag 3</li>
    <li class="drag">Drag 4</li>
    <li class="drag">Drag 5</li>
    <li class="drag">Drag 6</li>
    <li class="drag">Drag 7</li>
    <li class="drag">Drag 8</li>
    <li class="drag">Drag 9</li>
    <li class="drag">Drag 10</li>
    <li class="drag">Drag 11</li>
    <li class="drag">Drag 12</li>
</ul>
</div>


  var sort_opts = {
    helper: function(e, ui) {
      ui.children().each(function() {
        $(this).width($(this).width());
      });
      return ui;
    },
    stop: function(e, ui) {
      tableObj.siblings('.' + attrs.realm + '-reorder-weights').val(tableObj.sortable('toArray').toString());
    },
    axis: 'y',
    items: 'li.drag'
  };
  $('.draggable').sortable( sort_opts );
```

In Firefox, Chrome, etc dragging the handle to the bottom of the scrollable div will scroll the div. However, this is not the case for Internet Explorer (8,9)...

Is there a way to make it so that dragging the handle to be bottom of the scrollable div will also scroll the div in IE?

I tried doing `position:relative` on the div but now the div would scroll infinitely instead of stopping at the bottom so that's a no go....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I've managed to make a rather crude method by scrolling the div with javascript when the draggable is near the edges.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2cESH/

JS:

```
  var sort_opts = {
      helper: function (e, ui) {
          ui.children().each(function () {
              $(this).width($(this).width());
          });
          return ui;
      },
      stop: function (e, ui) {
          tableObj.siblings('.' + attrs.realm + '-reorder-weights').val(tableObj.sortable('toArray').toString());
      },
      sort: function (e, ui) {
          if($(ui.item).offset().top < 20 && $('#container-element').scrollTop() > 0){
              $('#container-element').scrollTop($('#container-element').scrollTop()-3);
          }
          if($(ui.item).offset().top > $('#container-element').height()-20 && $('#container-element').scrollTop() < $('#container-element ul').eq(0).height()){
              $('#container-element').scrollTop($('#container-element').scrollTop()+3);
          }
      },
      axis: 'y',
      items: 'li.drag'
  };
  $('.draggable').sortable(sort_opts);
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container-element" style="overflow-y:auto;max-height:100px;">
    <ul class="draggable">
        <li class="drag">Drag 1</li>
        <li class="drag">Drag 2</li>
        <li class="drag">Drag 3</li>
        <li class="drag">Drag 4</li>
        <li class="drag">Drag 5</li>
        <li class="drag">Drag 6</li>
        <li class="drag">Drag 7</li>
        <li class="drag">Drag 8</li>
        <li class="drag">Drag 9</li>
        <li class="drag">Drag 10</li>
        <li class="drag">Drag 11</li>
        <li class="drag">Drag 12</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: very nice! one problem though...dragging up the scrollable div isn't as smooth as dragging down...is there a way to make it so that dragging up is just as smooth as dragging down?

Comment: Does animating the `scrollTop` instead of directly setting it fix it? http://jsfiddle.net/2cESH/1/